# USB Abstract Control Module (ttyACM0) not available after reboot

Tags: debian, usb, proxmox

I have a [Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5](https://aeotec.com/z-wave-usb-stick/) device that is not available after reboot. The device, `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0658:0200 Sigma Designs, Inc. Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5 (ZW090) - UZB`, works fine if it is plugged in after the system has booted. Looking at `dmesg` upon plugging it in after boot shows:

```
[  369.999614] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  370.176704] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0658, idProduct=0200, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  370.176706] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  370.193113] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  370.195757] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  370.195757] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Conversely, just booting with the USB device plugged in it never is detected. Other USB devices, like mouse and keyboard, are detected during boot.

Is there a way to trigger the USB system to "rescan" (e.g., simulate the unplug and replug) during boot, possibly as a systemd unit? Or is this just a configuration issue?

The system is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (technically it is Proxmox VE 6.2-10) with a kernel of 5.4.44-2-pve.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe cdc_acm` and `man modprobe`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the `modprobe` yielded no results. Nothing appeared in `dmesg` after running it. Yet physically unplugging it triggers it to add. I have even tried https://zedt.eu/tech/linux/restarting-usb-subsystem-centos/ this to trigger the USB subsystem reloading and it does no good.